# probleme with old python scrip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm still republishing a python 2.x script in 3.x.
at some point, the script must replace the "print" function with "disp" (equivalent in TI basic language) except that it no longer works because of parentheses. anyone have an idea to fix it?
The code :

```
elif (line.find("print ")==idepth(line)):
        line = replace(line,"print ","Disp ")
        if (line[-1] == ","):
            line = line[:-1].rstrip() # Trailing , not legal for ti basic
```

thanks in advance

Edit: full code :

```
import sys
import os
import re
#GUI:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox

GUI_MODE = False
TAB_REPLACE = "    "

def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    global GUI_MODE

    print (args)
    if (len(args)==0):
        GUI_MODE=True
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        inp = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a python script to convert")
        if (inp==''):
            print ("cancelled")
            return 0
    else:
        inp=args[0]

    #now input file is known

    file=open(inp)
    prog = file.read().replace("\r","").split("\n") # Lines of code

    #Get a program name:
    if (prog[0][:1]=="#" and (prog[0].upper().find("NAME:")>-1 or prog[0].upper().find("PROGRAM:")>-1 )):
        outname=prog[0][prog[0].find(":")+1:]
    else:
        outname=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("File name","What do you want to name this program?")

    fixed = format(prog)

    #Write the converted program in this folder:
    print ("\n--Converted to TI-Basic code:--")
    print (fixed)
    print ("")
    print ("Making output files: "+outname+".tib, "+outname+".8xp ...")

    #Write the converted program in this folder:
    outfile=open(outname+".tib","w")
    outfile.write(fixed)
    outfile.close()

    #Write the .8xp program
    outfile=open(outname+".8xp","w")
    outfile.write(fixed)
    outfile.close()


    #assuming the compiler tibasic.exe is in this folder:
    if (sys.platform[:3]=="win"):
        if (os.system('tibasic.exe '+outname+'.tib')): #Returns non-0, error:
            errReport("Error trying to run tibasic.exe! Make sure it is in the current folder.")
    else:
        if (os.system('wine tibasic.exe '+outname+'.tib')): #Returns non-0, error:
            errReport("Error trying to run tibasic.exe! Make sure it is in the current folder, and w.i.n.e is installed.\n"+
            "(See http://www.winehq.org/ for installer)")
    os.remove(outname+".tib")
    a=input("Done! Press enter to exit:") #pause
    return 0

def format(linesArray): #converts lines from Python to ti-basic.
    for i in range(len(linesArray)):
        linesArray[i]=linesArray[i].replace("\t",TAB_REPLACE) #Important! see idepth()
    i=0;
    linesArray.append("") # 0-indent ending so blockAddEnd won't mess up.
    while (i<len(linesArray)):
        #Convert control blocks (if, for, while) from indented (python) to END (TI)
        line = linesArray[i]
        if isBlockStart(line,"for "):
            linesArray = blockAddEnd(linesArray, i, "End")
        elif isBlockStart(line,"if "):
            linesArray = blockAddEnd(linesArray, i, "End")
        elif isBlockStart(line,"while "):
            linesArray = blockAddEnd(linesArray, i, "End")
        elif isBlockStart(line,"repeat "): #not in python, but works on TI.
            linesArray = blockAddEnd(linesArray, i, "End")
        i+=1
    # Don't need indentations anymore, do the rest of the conversions:
    for i in range(len(linesArray)):
        linesArray[i]=convLine(linesArray[i],i+1)

    #Remove blanks:
    for i in range(linesArray.count("")):
        linesArray.remove("")

    return "\n".join(linesArray)

def convLine(line,num): #Line by line conversion.
    line = line.rstrip().lstrip() #trim indentation.
    lnum = "Line "+str(num)+": "

    if line.count("#"):
        comment = line[line.find("#"):]
        if (comment[0:6] == "#no-ti"):
            #Does not work on the ti.
            return ""
        elif (comment[0:4] == "#ti:"):
            # Only for ti:
            return comment[4:]
        else:
            line = line[:line.find("#")] # take comment off code

    #No imports in ti-basic!
    if line.startswith("import ") or (line.count(" import ") and line.startswith("from ")):
        return ""

    #Errors and warnings:
    if (toolong(line)):
        print (lnum+"Warning: Text string too long to fit on a TI83/84 screen. The calculator screen is 16 characters wide, 8 characters high.")
    if (line.find("\n")>-1):
        print (lnum+"Warning: newline \\n is not allowed in TI-Basic.")
    if (line.find("'''")>-1):
        print (lnum+"Warning: ''' quotes are not allowed, you must use \" quotes on a single line for TI-Basic.")
    if (replace(line,"pow(","")!=line):
        errReport(lnum+"TI calculators don't have the pow() command, you must use a**b instead of pow(a,b).")
    if (replace(line,"import ","")!=line):
        print (lnum+"import ignored. No import statements in TI-Basic!")
        return "" # ignore import statements!
    if (replace(line,"-=","")!=line):
        errReport(lnum+"The -= operator is not allowed.\nTry +=- or a=a+-number instead.")
    if (replace(line,"def ","")!=line):
        errReport(lnum+"Functions are not supported in TI-Basic! However, you can run another program with \"prgmPRGNAME\".")
    if (replace(line,"//","")!=line):
        print (lnum+"// division converted to / division: For int division, try int(a/b).")
        line=replace(line,"//","/")
    if (replace(line,"-","")!=line):
        print (lnum+"Warning: The - is changed to negative sign on the calculator. If you wanted to subtract, use a+-b instead of a-b.")
    if (replace(line,"open(","")!=line):
        errReport(lnum+"Error: TI calculators can't use \"open(filename)\" in programs. To store text, try using variables STR0, STR1, ... STR9.")
    if (replace(line,"%","")!=line):
        errReport(lnum+"Error: TI83/84 calculators don't have Mod.\n Instead of a % b, try (a/b-int(a/b))*b instead.")

    # Replace excess spaces, they cause errors in the calculator:
    line=replace(line,", ",",")
    line=replace(line," + ","+")
    line=replace(line," - ","-")
    line=replace(line," +- ","+-")
    line=replace(line," * ","*")
    line=replace(line," / ","/")
    line=replace(line," == ","==")
    line=replace(line," > ",">")
    line=replace(line," < ","<")
    line=replace(line," != ","!=")

    #TODO: Arrays converted to lists?


    line=replace(line,"theta","[theta]") # variable
    line=replace(line,"**","^")

    line=mathReplace(line)

    #round, max, min already works.
    line=replace(line,"float(","(")
    line=replace(line,"len(","dim(")
    line=replace(line,"math.pi","[pi]")
    line=replace(line,"math.e","[e]")
    line=replace(line,"eval(","expr(")
    line=replace(line,"-","[neg]") # use +- instead of - operator.
    line=replace(line,"==","=")
    line=replace(line," and ","&")
    line=replace(line," or ","|")
    line=replace(line,"random.random()","rand")
    line=replace(line,"random.randint","RandInt")
    line=replace(line,"int(","iPart(")

    if (replace(line,"input(","") != line):
        line=inputConv(line,num)

    if isBlockStart(line,"for "):
        line=forConv(line,num)
    elif (isBlockStart(line,"if ")):
        line = replace(line,"if ","If ")
        line = replace(line,":",":Then")
    elif (isBlockStart(line,"while ")):
        line = replace(line,"while ","While ")
        line = replace(line,":","")
    elif (isBlockStart(line,"repeat")):
        line = replace(line,"repeat","Repeat")
        line = replace(line,":","")
    elif (isBlockStart(line,"else")):
        line = replace(line,"else:","Else")
    elif isBlockStart(line,"elif"):
        errReport(lnum+"""Error: There is no else-if command on the TI83/84. However, you can use this instead:
if <condition>:
  ...
else:
  if <condition>:
    ...
  else:
    ...""")
    elif (line.find("print ")==idepth(line)):
        line = re.sub(r"print *\((.+)\)", r"disp \1", line)
        if (line[-1] == ","):
            line = line[:-1].rstrip() # Trailing , not legal for ti basic
    elif (replace(line,"=","")!=line): #assignment is -> on the calculator.
        eqspace = line.find("=")
        line = line[eqspace+1:].rstrip().lstrip() + "->" + line[:eqspace].rstrip().lstrip() # sto arrow.
        line = fixEQ(line)
    return replace(line,"+[neg]","-") #lastly, switch back the negative.

def fixEQ(line):
    # fix +=, *=, /=.
    # A+=1 changes to 1->A+, so fix it now.
    if (line[-1]=="+" or line[-1]=="*" or line[-1]=="/"):
        line = line[:-1].rstrip()+line[-1] # remove any spaces in "a  +" etc
        pre = line[line.find("->")+2:]
        #pre = pre[:-1].rstrip()+pre[-1]
        line= pre + "("+line[:line.find("->")]+")"+ line[line.find("->"):-1]
    return line

def inputConv(line,num):
    lnum = "Line "+str(num)+": "
    if (replace(line,"raw_input(","")!=line and line==replace(line,"=","")):
        #raw_input not assigned to variable is like Pause.
        return "Pause "
    else:
        var = line[:line.find("=")].rstrip().lstrip()
        if (len(var)>1 and var!="theta"): # might be invalid.
            print (lnum+"Warning: Program tries to store to variable \"%s\"." % var)
        prompt = line[line.find("input(")+6:]
        prompt = prompt[:prompt.find(")")]
        # Now return the TI basic input with var spaces removed:
        return "Input "+prompt+","+var

def forConv(line,num):
    lnum = "Line "+str(num)+": "
    # split "for i in range(...):"
    var = line[line.find("for ")+4:line.find(" in range")]
    #print var
    part = line[line.find("in range(")+9:] # only "...) : "
    part = part.rstrip(": ")[:-1] # remove extra " " or ":", remove last ).
    #print "'"+line+"'"
    out = part.split(",")
    if len(out)==1:
        return "For(%s,0,(%s)-1)" % (var, out[0])
    elif len(out)==2:
        return "For(%s,(%s),(%s)-1)" % (var, out[0], out[1])
    elif len(out)==3:
        return "For(%s,(%s),(%s)-1,(%s)" % (var, out[0], out[1], out[2])
    else:
        errReport(lnum+"Too many commas in for loop!")
        return "couldn't convert: "+line

def blockAddEnd(lines, startLine, endText):
    # Takes an array, line #, and end text.
    # Adds end for that indentation block.
    startInd = idepth(lines[startLine])
    if idepth(lines[startLine+1]) <= startInd:
        errReport("Expected indent after line "+str(startLine+1)+".")
    i = startLine+1
    #continue searching for the end while it's indented or it's an else line:
    while idepth(lines[i]) > startInd or (isBlockStart(lines[i],"else")):
        i+=1
    # now insert.
    lines.insert(i,endText)
    return lines

def idepth(text):
    # get indentation depth of line.
    depth=0
    line = text.replace("\t",TAB_REPLACE) #tab is 4 spaces.
    while (line[:1]==" "):
        line=line[1:]
        depth+=1
    return depth

def replace(text, changethis, tothis):
    # replaces text, but not in quotes.
    arr = text.split("\"")
    for i in range(0,len(arr),2):
        arr[i]=arr[i].replace(changethis, tothis)
    return "\"".join(arr)

def toolong(text):
    # checks for too long string:
    arr = text.split("\"")
    for i in range(1,len(arr),2):
        #print arr[i]
        if (len(arr[i]) > 16):
            return True
    return False

def parMatch(text,num): # given "(stuff()...()))", returns the parentheses block.
    lnum = "Line "+str(num)+": "
    for i in range(len(text)):
        part = text[:i-1]
        if (part.count("(")==part.count(")")):
            return part[1:-1] #without outside parentheses.
    errReport(lnum+"Invalid parentheses")

def isBlockStart(line, type):
    # Check if the line is start of a <type> block.
    # checks if it starts with <type>, and ends with ":".
    # example: isBlockStart("for i in range(8) : ","for") is true.
    return (line.find(type) == idepth(line) and line.rstrip(" ")[-1]==":")

def errReport(text):
    print (text)
    if (GUI_MODE):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error",text)
    sys.exit(1)

def mathReplace(line):
    """ Replaces mathematical functions with ti basic functions. """

    #Same function in both Python and TI-basic:
    same = ["sin", "cos", "tan", "asin", "acos", "atan", "sinh", "cosh", "tanh", "asinh", "acosh", "atanh"]
    line=replace(line,"math.sqrt(","[root]^2(")
    line=replace(line,"math.fabs(","abs(")
    for func in same:
        line = replace(line,"math.%s(" % func,func)
    line=replace(line,"math.log(","ln(")
    line=replace(line,"math.exp(","e^(")
    line=replace(line,"math.floor(","int(")
    line=replace(line,"math.log10(","log(")

    #same, but without "math." They might use
    #from math import sqrt etc...
    line=replace(line,"sqrt(","[root]^2(")
    line=replace(line,"fabs(","abs(")
    for func in same:
        line = replace(line, "%s(" % func,func)
    #(Redundant lines deleted)
    line=replace(line,"log(","ln(")
    line=replace(line,"exp(","e^(")
    line=replace(line,"floor(","int(")
    line=replace(line,"log10(","log(")

    return line

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

it's the original code with changement propose below

Comment: So you're trying to convert, for example, `print("Hello world!")` into `disp "Hello world!"`?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's regular expression library to perform more advanced string matching and replacement than `replace()`. Specifically, `re.sub()`, which functions the same as `replace()` but takes regular expressions instead of simple strings.

Be sure to first import it with `import re`. You can then do the following:

```py
elif (line.find("print ")==idepth(line)):
        line = re.sub(r"print *\(\"(.+)\"\)", r"disp \1", line)
        if (line[-1] == ","):
            line = line[:-1].rstrip() # Trailing , not legal for ti basic
```

This will look for a string of the format `"print("&1")"` or `"print ("&1")"` and replace it with `"disp &1"`, where `&1` is the contents between the quotes.

Edit: You had initially specified that you wanted the output "without the quotes", but it seems you've edited that comment. If you want to include the quotes in the output, use this line instead:

```py
line = re.sub(r"print *\((.+)\)", r"disp \1", line)
```

Comment: it does not work it continues to interpret the print function in
priPart (a) instead of print (a) suddenly it replaces it in PRent a

Comment: @souréNardenla can you give a better example of what input you're trying to convert?

Comment: The goal is to convert simple python scripts into TIbasic script (for texas instrument calculator) the whole script works but it cannot convert the "print" instruction to "Disp".As an example, I first want to convert this program: a = 2 print (a) which should give 2-> a Disp a (-> represent the arrow of Ti basic) except that it does not work the TI basic program is a -> 2 PRent a (PRent not existing as an TI basic)
I'm going to display the whole code above because I think it may be from a variable declared above but I must admit that I don't see which one could be incriminate

Comment: @souréNardenla If I do `convLine("print (a)", 1)` I get `disp a` so I believe that function is working right. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I have put the complete code above but do not bother I will try to refine the search field. Do you have any idea what might not work in general? I personally think about the definition of variable to update but I'm not sure

Comment: Kind of trying to look at your code holistically- shouldn't you do ```elif (line.find("print")==idepth(line)):``` (without space after ```print ```) there? I mean you won't necessarily get this space after ```print``` in python 3

Comment: I found the error it "was enough" to replace elif (line.find ("print") == idepth (line)):
        line = replace (line, "print", "Disp")
by elif (line.find ("priPart") == idepth (line)):
line = replace (line, "priPart", "Disp")
I don't really know what "priPart" is, maybe the contraction of print and parenthesis
in any case thank you to both of you for taking the time to advise me and help me it is you who put me on the right voice

Comment: @souréNardenla I'm glad you were able to solve the problem! You should click the green checkmark to accept the answer so the question can be marked as closed.

Comment: C'est fait merci a vous